# How do I resize an image with google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

so I tried this

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody;
function Issac() {

  var fileId = '1QAsyRGeQvz8L2VesbItTCHAEQKN0P2T6';
  var img = DriveApp.getFilesByName('shrok.jpg');
  var blobFish = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/949582948907306301/A7560C16C1D8D9778C52D24BBB86184E30F70E41/");



  doc.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(blobFish.getBlob());
}
```

But im not even sure how to get started on setting the width or setting the height of the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.setHeight()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image.html#setheightheight) and [`.setWidth()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image.html#setwidthwidth) on the image returned by [`.appendInlineImage()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#appendinlineimageimage_1).

I've included here a way to scale it by percentage, but both of those height/width methods accept pixel values. You can modify to fit your needs.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody;
function Issac() {

  var fileId = '1QAsyRGeQvz8L2VesbItTCHAEQKN0P2T6';
  var img = DriveApp.getFilesByName('shrok.jpg');
  var blobFish = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/949582948907306301/A7560C16C1D8D9778C52D24BBB86184E30F70E41/");

  var image = doc.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(blobFish.getBlob());
  var scale = 0.5; // scale the image by 50%
  image.setWidth(image.getWidth() * scale);
  image.setHeight(image.getHeight() * scale);
}
```